# Set loading gif in UIWebView while it's loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I'm searching for an easy method to display a custom loading .gif or another image as long as a UIWebView is still loading the page.

I know I have to do it in

```
– webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

But how do I load the image?

Comment: What exactly is the gif, because you can use a UIActivityView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
    – webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

        UIImageView   *animatedImages;
        NSMutableArray *imageArray;

            // Array to hold jpg images
        imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:IMAGE_COUNT];

            // Build array of images, cycling through image names
        for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
            [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourGifImage%d.jpg", i]]];

            // Animated images - centered on screen
        animatedImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH)];

           animatedImages.center = self.webView.center;

        animatedImages.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];

            // One cycle through all the images takes 1 seconds
        animatedImages.animationDuration = 1.0;

            // Repeat forever
        animatedImages.animationRepeatCount = 0;

        animatedImages.tag = 1;

        [animatedImages startAnimating];

            // Add to webview
        [self.webView addSubview:animatedImages];

    }
```

and in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method remove it from superview

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    UIView * removeAminatingImages = [self.webView viewWithTag:1];
    [removeAminatingImages removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting implementation for an animating image, but I think what is more suited is a UIActivityView

Comment: can you tell me why the images end with .lpg and do i just take all frams of my gif as png??

Comment: ok, i added 9 png's and defined IMAGE_COUNT and HEIGHT and WIDTH but it's not showing. It is still a blank white screen

Comment: @spankmaster79 did 'webViewDidStartLoad:' get called? And also check that **delegate** is set correctly

Comment: @Gyani yes it get's called and runs through fine. WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;   
}

Comment: @Gyani sorry for the confusion... wrong index in image names ;-)